# PrintWriter closing too early

Tags: java, printwriter

I am using the PrintWriter class to write text from a server to a file.  My program is creating the file, but there is no output.  Can someone please advise me of what is incorrect with this snippet of my code?  Cheers.

```
public class WriteFile {
        PrintWriter logFileWriter;

        public WriteFile() {

        }

        void startLogFile(String logName) {

            File file = new File(logName);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                logFileWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        void printToFile(String text) {
            logFileWriter.printf(text + "\n");

        }

        void closeLogFile() {

            logFileWriter.close();
            logFileWriter = null;

        }
    //} remove this extra bracket which caused building error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't calling closeLogFile() in your code. Set a breakpoint to double check.

Comment: I am calling closeLogFile() @ samoz

Comment: I think it is closing before all of the file information downloads.  Any ideas on how I can test to see if this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

After editing and testing your code block, I could output text. Steps included startLogFile, printToFile, closeLogFile. Did you forget calling closeLogFile somewhere?

```
        WriteFile writeFile = new WriteFile();
        writeFile.startLogFile("test");
        writeFile.printToFile("hahaha");
        writeFile.closeLogFile();
```